# Call function from calling object

Tags: java

This is for a personal project. Not assignment or work.
Say I have an object, `objA` that has a function `callB()`.

When I run `callB()` it calls a function in object B. The function in `objB` can have calls to functions in objA.

Eg. `objA` calls `callB()`.
Inside `callB()` there is a function like `setObjAName()` which sets a variable on `objA`.

How would I do this in Java? How do I reference `objA` from `objB`?

Comment: You pass a reference to objA to objB, for example with a `setObjA(A a)` method.

Comment: Write a class called A. Write a class called  B. Add a method called callB in class A and create a new instance of B and call the setObjName method and pass it this. That being said, why do you want a cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to simply pass a reference to A in with the method call, which will allow for B to access any of A's public methods.

```
public class ClassA {

    public String someAVar;

    public void callB(ClassA a){
        //do stuff
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.setObjA(this,"newValue");
    }
}
public class ClassB{
    public void setObjA(ClassA A, String newValue){
        A.someAVar = newValue;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you might want the variable to be settable without passing in a particular instance, in which case static methods and variables are your friend.

```
public class ClassA {

    public static String someAVar;

    public void callB(){
        //do stuff
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.setObjA("newValue");
    }
}


public class ClassB{
    public void setObjA(String newValue){
        ClassA.someAVar = newValue;
    }
}
```